# MySQL in Docker container

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets, docker

Currently I have a Docker container that hosts a webpage (mostly php).  Right now the database is stored on a server on AWS.  For development purposes I want to create a local database in the Docker container.  I did some googling around and it seems like most people recommend creating an entire separate container for hosting the mysql.  Since this is only a database for development I am wondering if I can avoid the effort of setting up another container and put MySQL in directly in the container that hosts the webpage.  To do this I tried installing MySQL-Server:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Mysql installed fine doing this.  Then I tried to run the MySQL interactive shell:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

When I did this I got the following error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Can I run the mysql in the same Docker container or am I going to need to create a separate one?

Comment: hi @tyler-hilbert, have you tried `mysql -u root -p`?

Comment: @Andy K um yea, that's the command that gave the error in the question

Comment: sorry @tyler-hilbert very late here. I'll have a look tomo morning.

Comment: @AndyK Alright cool

Answer (score 2):

There is really no effort in setting up separate MySQL container. Real effort is to install it inside existing container.

I would recommend that you create docker compose file and define application and database containers (make sure you have docker compose installed on your dev environment, in most cases it should be already installed).

Create a file docker-compose.yml (you can create it in the same folder where Dockerfile is for you project, usually project root folder) with following content:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: your_app_docker_image_name
    ...more config options depending on your project (volumes, ports, etc)
  db:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - './user/db:/var/lib/mysql'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
```

To start your project run

```
docker-compose up
```

This will lift your app container and separate MySQL container (without root password intentionally since this is for dev purpose).
Now you can access mysql server from your app container like this

```
mysql -h db -u root
```

Using docker compose you can setup complex environments easily. And when deploying to production or other test environment you don't need to change your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

There are many pros to have separate containers for each service. 
To have php+apache+mysql in the same container you either have to find an image like this https://github.com/tutumcloud/lamp, or build it yourself from a Dockerfile.

But try to imagine one day you decide to switch your db storage engine from Mysql to Percona or Maria, or you would like to start using Memcached/Redis for your application. Either of the above won't be any problem if you have your services as separate containers.